# Dúvida com htaccess (local X hospedagem)

Tags: php, htaccess

Olá, 
Estou fazendo um projeto e fui adiciona-lo on-line para fazer um teste, localmente tudo funciona, tenho o meu “.htaccess” assim:

```
Options All -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?ruta=$1
```

No servidor as páginas não estão sendo encontradas, estou usando desta forma a baixo, agradeço a ajuda:

```
Options All -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^meusite.com.br$ [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.meusite.com.br$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !pastadosite/
RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?ruta=$1
```